# Use .htaccess in Nextcloud to have pretty URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, nextcloud

I would like to change the last part of this URL:

> cloud.example.com/apps/files/?dir=/Documents&fileid=1303128

to

> cloud.example.com/apps/files/Documents

i.e. remove the `"?dir=/"` string and the rest from `"&fileid=...."`

Tried various solutions, but none with a proper result. FWIW, restarted apache after every single change. I would appreciate your help. Rewrite already works for removing index.php from the URL.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried (please include already existing rewrites)?

Comment: I haven't kept notes.......... sad enough. Normally is my habit, Really tried dozens of options/rules

Comment: Where in your pretty URL you want to specify fileid?